# How to get the month and format it to its written form

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date in "dd/mm/yy" format and I want to make it "dd of month of yyyy". The problem is I want it in Portuguese so it's "dd de month de yyyy" so if I do the normal way of formatting (```Format(Date, "dd de mmmm de yyyy")´´´) the "d" in the word "de" gets mixed up with the day.

How do I solve this?

I tried this

```
dados.Range("L" & linha).Value = Day(prcs.Range("B17")) & " de " & Format(Month(prcs.Range("B17")), mmmm) & " de " & Year(prcs.Range("B17"))
```

And what I get for a date like 12/05/18 is " 12 de 5 de 2018" instead of what I expected "12 de maio de 2018".

I also tried storing the month in another variable and formating it from there, but I either messed it up or it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d` is a reserved format mask character representing the day of the month without a leading zero. To use it explicitly as a literal string, escape it with a backslash or use quotes. Since you have to double up quotes within a quoted string, the backslash seems more appropriate.

```
'Format(Date, "dd \d\e mmmm \d\e yyyy")
dados.Range("L" & linha).Value = Date
dados.Range("L" & linha).NumberFormat = "dd \d\e mmmm \d\e yyyy"
'with quoted literal string
dados.Range("L" & linha).NumberFormat = "dd ""de"" mmmm ""de"" yyyy"
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to give the format as a string `"mmmm"`, i.e.: `Format(Month(prcs.Range("B17")), "mmmm")`.

This would get highlighted if you had `Option Explicit` at the top of your code.
[image]